# How do I embed a Xamarin Forms Control Into native UWP Page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I've been doing this in this way: put LoadApplication(new Forms.App()) in code behind
but today I have been told that can embed a Xamarin Forms Control Into native UWP Page, how?
Could someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: this is a feature of XF 3.0, which is still in preview

Comment: thx,but is there any idear how to implement in XF2.3

Comment: As Jason said 3.0 preview+ : https://blog.xamarin.com/unleashed-embedding-xamarin-forms-in-xamarin-native/